# Move On To Next Record If Condition Not Met

Tags: c#, ado.net, datareader

I am trying to move on to the next record in the DataReader if a condition is not met. I am aware that DataReaders are foward-only, so what I am trying to achieve is; while data read, move on to the next record if column x has a null value;

```cs
using (OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    try
    { 
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (!dr.IsDBNull(0))
            {
                ID = dr.GetString(0).ToString();
            }                     
            if (!dr.IsDBNull(1))
            {
                REFERENCE = dr.GetString(1);
            }
            else
            {
                //this is where I need it to 'abandon' the current record and move on to the next...
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        dr.Close();
        dr.Dispose();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

I have only put in the part of the code which is relevant so that it's short and straight to the point. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: then do nothing ... Read is what moving to the next record ... (eventually you can force wihile  loop to iterate with right C# keyword)

Comment: from **Learn  .NET / C# guide / Language reference / Iteration statements - for, foreach, do, and while** official documentation: *You can step to the next iteration in the loop using the ...*

Comment: Why don't you just query for the right data to begin with? It's something a database is relatively good at.

Comment: And BTW: The using statement will take care of Close and Dispose on the DataReader. You don't need that in the finally section.

Comment: @PalleDue Thank you for the response - I've noted re the Using statement and will also consider updating the source query to exclude any bad data. Thank you.

Comment: @Selvin Ah, got you - thank you for the pointer. So Read is what moves to the next record...thank you for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To skip the current record in the `DataReader` and move on to the next record if a condition is not met, you can use the `continue` statement. The `continue` statement allows you to skip the remaining code within the current iteration of the loop and move on to the next iteration. Here's how you can modify your code:

```cs
using (OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    try
    { 
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (!dr.IsDBNull(0))
            {
                ID = dr.GetString(0);
            }                     
            if (!dr.IsDBNull(1))
            {
                REFERENCE = dr.GetString(1);
            }
            else
            {
                // Skip the current record and move on to the next
                continue;
            }
            
            // Rest of your code for processing the current record
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        dr.Close();
        dr.Dispose();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

By using `continue`, when the `IsDBNull` condition for column 1 is met, the code will skip the remaining code within the current iteration of the loop and move on to the next iteration, effectively moving to the next record in the `DataReader`.

Comment: Ha! You, sir, are a lifesaver! That's exactly what I was looking for. Feel very silly that the answer was so simple. Amazing what one word can achieve, haha. Thank you so much :)

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: Or does cChatGPT look like this answer?

Comment: As noted on another of your answers, [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: This is not an AI used answer